# Android Studio/Kotlin - Type inference failed not enough information to infer parameter

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, illegalstateexception

I'm trying to migrate my app to AndroidX, I changed everything in code and layouts, etc.
The only thing where I am stuck is this:

"Type inference failed not enough information to infer parameter T in fun  Observer(function:(t: T!) - Unit): Observer
Please specify it explicitly"

Also, when trying to rebuild, I receive this error

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: SimpleTypeImpl should not be created for error type: ErrorScope{Error scope for class <ERROR CLASS> with arguments: org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.IndexedParametersSubstitution@5852441e}
[ERROR : LiveData<FeedPostLikes>]
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.SimpleTypeImpl.<init>(KotlinTypeFactory.kt:219)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.KotlinTypeFactory.simpleTypeWithNonTrivialMemberScope(KotlinTypeFactory.kt:149)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.KotlinTypeFactory.simpleType(KotlinTypeFactory.kt:76)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.KotlinTypeFactory.simpleType$default(KotlinTypeFactory.kt:70)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.TypeSubstitutionKt.replace(TypeSubstitution.kt:141)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.TypeSubstitutionKt.replace(TypeSubstitution.kt:126)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.TypeSubstitutionKt.replace$default(TypeSubstitution.kt:118)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.KaptAnonymousTypeTransformer.convertPossiblyAnonymousType(KaptAnonymousTypeTransformer.kt:72)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.KaptAnonymousTypeTransformer.convertPossiblyAnonymousType(KaptAnonymousTypeTransformer.kt:69)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.KaptAnonymousTypeTransformer.transformAnonymousType(KaptAnonymousTypeTransformer.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.DescriptorResolver.transformAnonymousTypeIfNeeded(DescriptorResolver.java:1023)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.VariableTypeAndInitializerResolver$resolveTypeNullable$1.invoke(VariableTypeAndInitializerResolver.kt:94)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.VariableTypeAndInitializerResolver$resolveTypeNullable$1.invoke(VariableTypeAndInitializerResolver.kt:26)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:352)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:408)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.DeferredType.getDelegate(DeferredType.java:109)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.WrappedType.getAnnotations(KotlinType.kt:127)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.forceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.doForceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.forceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.forceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.forceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.doForceResolveAllContents(LazyClassDescriptor.java:573)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.lambda$new$4(LazyClassDescriptor.java:216)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:352)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.forceResolveAllContents(LazyClassDescriptor.java:561)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.doForceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:75)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.forceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension$doAnalysis$1.invoke(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension$doAnalysis$1.invoke(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:34)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doForEachDeclaration(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:121)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doForEachDeclaration(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:135)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doAnalysis(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:63)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.doAnalysis(Kapt3Extension.kt:145)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:557)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:548)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:177)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:165)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:55)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:104)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:349)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:237)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.access$compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:37)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner$compile$2.invoke(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:606)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1645)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

can't get rid of it...

[image]

```
setupAuthGuard { uid ->
        setupBottomNavigation(uid, 0)
        mViewModel = initViewModel()
        mViewModel.init(uid)
        mViewModel.feedPosts.observe(this, Observer {
            it.let {
                mAdapter.updatePosts(it)
            }
        })
        mViewModel.goToCommentsScreen.observe(this, Observer {
            it?.let { postId ->
                CommentsActivity.start(this, postId)
            }
        })
    }
}

override fun toggleLike(postId: String) {
    Log.d(TAG, "toggleLike: $postId")
    mViewModel.toggleLike(postId)
}

override fun loadLikes(postId: String, position: Int) {
    if (mViewModel.getLikes(postId) == null) {
        mViewModel.loadLikes(postId).observe(this, Observer {
            it.let { postLikes ->
                mAdapter.updatePostLikes(position, postLikes)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also post the code from the mViewModel where you declared the LiveData that you want to observe?

Comment: did you find any solution ? I am getting this error also, which is [ERROR : ArrayList<BaseFragment>]